# Find out all solutions for the system

Tags: matrix-equations

Given the system
$$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  x_1&x_2&x_3&k\\
  x_1&x_2&kx_3&1\\
  x_1&kx_2&x_3&1\\
  kx_1&x_2&x_3&1\\
\end{array}
\right] $$
I tried to solve this...It looks simple but I found a problem at the end...
$$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  1&1&1&k\\
  1&1&k&1\\
  1&k&1&1\\
  k&1&1&1\\
\end{array}
\right] $$
$$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  1&1&1&k\\
  0&0&k-1&1-k\\
  0&k-1&0&1-k\\
  k-1&0&0&1-k\\
\end{array}
\right] $$
$$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  1&1&1&k\\
  0&0&1& \frac{1-k}{k-1}\\
  0&1&0& \frac{1-k}{k-1}\\
  1&0&0& \frac{1-k}{k-1}\\
\end{array}
\right] $$
Finally,
$$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  1&0&0& -1\\
  0&1&0& -1\\
  0&0&1& -1\\
  0&0&0&k+3\\
\end{array}
\right] $$
There is no way to get infinitely many solutions.
$$$$
However, I tried to put the system into other online calculator...
[Click me](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a%2Bb%2Bc%3D-1,a%2Bb%2Bck%3D1,a%2Bbk%2Bc%3D1,ak%2Bb%2Bc%3D1,%20when%20k%3D4)$$$$
There is infinitely many solutions when k=4 or other numbers. What's wrong of my work...

Comment: In step 1, looks like you put $x_1=x_2=x_3=1.$ But they might not even be all equal, certainly not all $1.$

Comment: You have divided by $k-1$, hence if it is $0$, you have a problem. For $k=1$, you have obviously infinitely many solutions.

Comment: Hummm...It only means the coefficient of x_1, x_2 and x_3 are 1

Comment: I was so careless...@Kelenner Thanks for your notice!:)

Comment: You are welcome !

Answer (score 1):

Let us add the last three equations to gather to get: $$(k+2)(x_1+x_2+x_3) =3$$
Then we use the first one to get, $$(k+2)(k)=3 \implies k=1, -3$$

So, ?

Answer (score 0):

The system has solutions only if

$\det(A|B)=0$, otherwise $\text{rank }(A|B)=4>\text{rank }(A)$

that is $k^4-6 k^2+8 k-3=0\to (k-1)^3 (k+3)=0$

for $k=-3$ and $k=1$

for $k=-3$ we get the system

$\begin {cases}
x+y+z=-3\\
x+y-3 z=1\\
x-3 y+z=1\\
-3x+y+z=1\\
\end{cases}
$

which has solution $(-1,-1,-1)$

for $k=1$ we get

$\begin {cases}
x+y+z=1\\
x+y+ z=1\\
x+y+z=1\\
x+y+z=1\\
\end{cases}
$

that is

$x+y+z=1$ which gives infinite solutions

$(t,u,1-t-u)$

Hope this helps